# Assigning new value to all array elements

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do something like this below?  I initialize an int array whose all elements are -1.  Is there a way of assigning a new value to all elements like below?

```
int[] arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
arr = {0,1,2,5,7,18,20};
```

---

What i was trying to do is below.  There is a lot of `case`s (i just ut three here) I was close the first time around... It needs to be  `arr = new[]{0,1,2,5,7,18,20};` in the lines below

```
private int[] getComboArray(int toLocation)
{
    int[] arr = new int[7];
    switch (toLocation)
    {
        case 0:
            arr = {0,1,2,5,7,18,20} ; //<-------
            break;  
        case 1:
            arr = {2,3,2,4,4,19,20} ; //<-------
            break;
        case 2:
            arr = {4,3,2,5,4,11,10} ; //<-------
            break;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you initialize as `int[] arr = {0,1,2,5,7,18,20};`?

Comment: You're effectively doing that already? :S

Comment: I was thinking of initializing it to all -1 then a `switch()` would run and depending on what value is being evaluated the int array will have different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//you can overwrite your previous array like this
int[] arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
arr = new int[] {0,1,2,5,7,18,20};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int[] arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
new int[] {0,1,2,5,7,18,20}.CopyTo(arr, 0);
```

The address of the original array `arr` is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there isn't enough information in your question to really identify what you need to accomplish.  Technically, it's pretty easy to assign new values to individual elements in the array, like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

If you wanted all of your array elements to follow a specific pattern, like the above... You should just initialize it that way:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 18, 20 };
```

If you don't know what the values are but you have a source array and a destination array, then copying is another method:

```
int[] sourceArray = null;
// Something happens to fill your source array.
int[] destArray = new int[7];
Array.Copy(sourceArray, destArray, destArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can asssign **new** values using again the `new` keyword.

```
int[] arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
arr =  new[] {0,1,2,5,7,18,20}; // 0,1,2,5,7,18,20
```

Using this, your function will look like below.

```
private int[] getComboArray(int toLocation)
{
    int[] arr = new int[7];
    switch (toLocation)
    {
        case 0:
            arr =  new [] {0,1,2,5,7,18,20} ; //<--
            break;  
        case 1:
            arr = new []{2,3,2,4,4,19,20} ; //<--
            break;
        case 2:
            arr =new [] {4,3,2,5,4,11,10} ; //<--
            break;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

---

If you want to append new elements to the current array, you can create a `List` of the new elements and to append the array to it, after that you can convert it back to array.

```
int[] arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
var concat = new List<int> {0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 18, 20};
concat.AddRange(arr);
arr = concat.ToArray(); // -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,2,5,7,18,20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
int[] arrTT = {0,1,2,5,7,18,20}

for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
{
   arr[i]=arrTT[i];
}
```